# Defining a Neighborhood Around a Point Whose Elements Have Different Units

Tags: general-topology, geometry, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics

Suppose I have some n-dimensional point

$ \mathbf{x} = [x_1,...,x_n] $

where some of the $x_i$ have different units (for example, $x_1$ in Ohms and $x_5$ in seconds). Now if all the elements had the same units I could define a ball $B$ of radius $r$ around $\mathbf{x}$ by

$ B_r(\mathbf{x}) = \{ \mathbf{y} : ||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|| \leq r\}$

But because the elements of the point do not have the same units, the norm $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||$ is not meaningful if it is taken to be the Euclidean norm or something similar.

How could one define a meaningful distance in this space in order to define a ball of a particular radius around a point? My first approach is to consider that each element $x_i$ is bounded by some interval with a minimum $m_i$ and a maximum $M_i$ such that

$x_i \in [m_i, M_i]$

and then define a radius for each element by

$r^*_i = \frac{1}{(M_i-m_i)}r$

Then I could define a "ball" of points around the point in question by

$ B_r(\mathbf{x}) = \{ \mathbf{y} : |x_i - y_i| \leq r^*_i\}$

But I am not sure that this is meaningful. Ultimately I am trying to define a ball of parameters for a dynamical model around a particular parameter, and the model is to be evaluated at each point of this ball (a "parameter hypersphere" instead of a parameter grid). Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: If I'm interpreting your question correctly, at some point you will need to decide how to compare electrical current to time (how 1 Ohm compares to 1 second). This requires physical knowledge/intuition. I don't think there's any way around that. Once you decide on the scalings, you can nondimensionalise everything and can forget about the physical units/interpretation when calculating distances. I don't understand what you mean by a "parameter hypersphere" and a "parameter grid", are you just saying you don't want to allow all combinations of the variables?

Comment: @David A parameter grid is just a colloquial term among people who do computational modeling in my field, called as such because it is usually a grid of points $(x,y)$ of two parameters for a model. I thought that by extending the notion to a hypersphere (since I'm dealing with about nine parameters instead of two and I want parameter combinations equidistant from a point) might make my question clearer to those who do computational modeling.

Comment: Once you nondimensionalise, using $x_i\rightarrow x_i/(M_i-m_i)$ or some other scale (maybe $x_i\rightarrow(x_i-m_i)/(M_i-m_i)$ so $0\leq x_i\leq 1$ if you want different quantities weighted evenly), you can use whatever distance metric you want on the $x_i$'s. The hardest part will be working out what value of $r$ to use, and what it means physically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any metric formed in the way you speak of will be topologically equivalent to the standard Euclidean one whose coordinates will be your 'meaningless' Ohms-seconds-etc.  This is because in finite dimensions over $\mathbb{R}$ the normal Euclidean metric is equivalent to the 'taxi-cab metric' which considers the sums of the distances in each variable.  Scaling each one-dimensional distance by the (presumed non-zero) factors $(M_i - m_i)^{-1}$ will again give you an equivalent metric.  This is a basic exercise in topology: You can easily show that for any point, in either metric you can find neighborhoods (e.g. n-dimensional rectangular prisms centered around the point with side lengths converging to zero) that are bases for the different topologies but which are nested in each other.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know much topology and had completely forgotten about the $L_1$ distance. This definitely solves the problem.